# Copy parent URL to php variable

Tags: php

The following code copy the URL of my "index.php" page

```
$url = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

But I need to add this code to another website in iframe, so I need to get the URL of the other website as a parent URL

Comment: If you are setting the other website in the iframe, don't you already have it? Also, iframe is html and php has no concept of what html does or is doing. By the time you see the html, php is done and isn't doing anything more.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're talking about the referring URL. Use this

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

in the iframed page

Comment: My code show this URL: www.mydomain.com/index.php and your code show this URL: www.mydomain.com but I want to show the parent website URL: www.otherdomain.com

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay in response. If you're viewing `www.mydomain.com/index.php` from an iframe in `www.otherdomain.com`, having `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in `www.mydomain.com/index.php` should give you `www.otherdomain.com`

Comment: I'm using this code inside Fancybox iframe, so it didn't give me www.otherdomain.com, it just give me my domain www.mydomain.com